# trigger jquery on document.form.element.value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, triggers

I have 2 drop-down menus (select1 and select2) and 1 input text (rate). When selecting a value in select1, it changes in select2. When I select a value in select2, the value appears in the input text. Now what I want is to change the input text to change when the select2 is changed by the select1 trigger. But that doesn't work. I tried change, blur... but it didn't help.

Any idea?

```
$('#select1').change( function() { 
    $.post("includes/functions.php", {select1: ""+$(this).val()+""},
      function(data){
        var objet = JSON.parse(data);       
        ...
        $("#select2").val(objet.select2value); //That works!
      }
}
```

and then:

```
$('#select2').bind('keyup blur change focus click', function(){
  $.post("includes/functions.php", {
    rate: ""+$(this).val()+"" }, function(data){
       var objet = JSON.parse(data);
       /* That works when I change select2 directly in the drop-down;
          not when select2 changed by changing select1 */
       document.form.rate.value = objet.rate;  
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)? Such as: `$("#select2").trigger("change");`

Comment: Using `trigger("change")` doesn't change the input text at all. Or then i would need to put the second function into the first one; but that's what I wanted to avoid. Also because the input text should be able to be triggered by select2 only; without select1.

Comment: Well, you could always create an extra function, that is triggered whenever any of the two change. And have that one make the post to get the rate from the server and update the input value.

Comment: Changing the value with code does not trigger an event, you must trigger it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about refactoring the logic outside of the second handler, and invoking it on both events:

```
$('#select1').change( function() { 
    $.post("includes/functions.php", {select1: ""+$(this).val()+""},
      function(data){
        var objet = JSON.parse(data);       
        ...
        $("#select2").val(objet.select2value);
        updateRate();
      }
}

$('#select2').change( function(){
  updateRate();
});

function updateRate() {
    $.post("includes/functions.php", {
        rate: ""+ $('#select2').val() +"" }, function(data){
           var objet = JSON.parse(data);
           document.form.rate.value = objet.rate;  
      });
}
```